# doMPI and user-defined packages

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, dompi

I am starting to use `doMPI`, and I user a package I have defined by myself.

First, I have in my file to be executed:

```
library(doMPI)
cl <- startMPIcluster() 
registerDoMPI(cl)
```

Note: I am not using `cl <- startMPIcluster(count)`, since I believe it is better to specify the number of cores "outside" the function, but it is not clear to me if doing `cl <- startMPIcluster()` is the right way or not.

And then, after loading my package through `library(my_package)`

```
myres <- foreach(t2 = 1550:1551) %dopar% {my_function(t2)}
```

using `mpirun` has resulted in

> Evaluation error: could not find function "my_function"

But the function `my_function` is recognized in the cluster: when I run `my_function` without `MPI`, the results are correct.

Then, I have changed the call to:

```
myres <- foreach(t2 = 1550:1551) %dopar% {my_package::my_function(t2)}
```

and then it has started to run, so adding `my_package::` has allowed `mpirun` to understand what `my_function` is. Which is something odd, since I have run before library(my_package).

But after starting to run, there is another error:

> "Evaluation error: could not find function "my_function_2"."

`my_function_2` is a defined function on my package.

Of course, one possibility would be to go to all the functions in my package, and when there is a call to another function, just add `my_package::`.

But I believe that this is not what it should be, so I guess that there is an underlying error/badly-used-instruction that I cannot see.

Any idea on what could be going on wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Study `help("foreach")` and pay special attention to the `.packages` parameter.

Comment: That was it, Roland, than you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize the workers using the foreach `.packages` option:

```
myres <-
  foreach(t2=1550:1551, .packages='my_package') %dopar% {
    my_function(t2)
  }
```

This causes each of the cluster workers to load `my_package`. Loading a package in the master process doesn't cause it to be loaded by the cluster workers, which is why `.packages` is necessary.

As for `startMPIcluster`, I never use the `count` argument unless I'm executing the R script without `mpirun` (which limits you to running on a single node). If `count` isn't specified, `startMPIcluster` gets all it's information from mpirun, making the script more flexible.